# Is there a Tutorial for Debugging in android? the Selection in my listview was not shown

Tags: android, listview, debugging

in my app i have created a custom arrayadapter for a custom listview.
But the  Contextual Action Bar dont mark my selected items.
i had a look on a tutorial but i dont see the problem.

I want to find the issue by myself, so i find the debug button put a break point(red dot) in my program and look step after step in my code. 
But the debugger jumps also in common java code i.e. Toast.java and in there are a lot of errors shown.

Maybe its to late and i am confused.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Assuming you are using **Android Studio** then [Debug Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html). There are plenty of other tutorials. Try a search such as **android studio debugging tutorial**

Comment: shame on me. thx MikeT